# Sum entries in List3 with index from List1 when List1 == List2

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

So I am trying to make a sum from List3 based on the index from List1 when `List1 == List2`.  I am pretty sure the problem is the `List3[y]` at the beginning of this statement, but I can't figure out what to put instead.

This comprehension is to replace the nested for loop also posted (which works as expected).

Thanks in advance.

```
#This loop works as intended, but takes a long time
for y in range(len(List1)):
    for x in range(len(List2)):
        if List1[y] == List2[x]:
            sumValue += List3[y]   


#Trying to build using this list comprehension sum
sumValue = sum([List3[y] for y, val1 in enumerate(List1) for x, val2 in enumerate(List2) if val1==val2])
```

Comment: Is there any error/unintended behavior? Please be specific.

Comment: Could you add an input example and the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

First, stick with PEP8 on variable names: `list1` instead of `List1`.

Second, I think your list comprehension is ok, but you can simplify it.

*Note: I assume that `len(list1) == len(list3)`.*

## If elements of `list2` are unique

You want to know if `val1` is in `list2`. There is the `in` operator to achieve this:

```
sum([list3[i] for i, v in enumerate(list1) if v in list2])
```

Looking for a value in a list has a O(n) time complexity, but if you convert the list to a set, the complexity is O(1):

```
set2 = set(list2)
sum([list3[i] for i, v in enumerate(list1) if v in set2])
```

Will be *really faster*.

Finally, you can remove the brackets, since `sum` accepts a generator:

```
set2 = set(list2)
sum(list3[i] for i, v in enumerate(list1) if v in set2)
```

Here is a simple benchmark:

```
>>> list1=[random.randint(0,10000) for _ in range(10000)]
>>> list2=[random.randint(0,10000) for _ in range(10000)]
>>> list3=[random.randint(0,10000) for _ in range(10000)]
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: sum(list3[i] for i, v in enumerate(list1) if v in list2), number=100)
61.139454132004175
>>> set2 = set(list2)
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: sum(list3[i] for i, v in enumerate(list1) if v in set2), number=100)
0.09698906799894758
```

If you want to remove indices, you can use `zip`:

```
sum(v3 for v1, v3 in zip(list1, list3) if v1 in set2)
```

This version seems a little faster than the previous one:

```
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: sum(v3 for v1, v3 in zip(list1, list3) if v1 in set2), number=100)
0.07421852700645104
```

## If elements of `list2` are not unique

You want to know *how many times* `val1` is in `list2`. (That's what you code does: for every element `list1[i]`, add `list3[i]` *for every element* of `list2` that is equal to `list[i]`: **if you have 3 times `list1[i]` in `list2`, add 3 times `list3[i]` to the result**). You can use `collections.Counter`:

```
>>> import collections
>>> c2 = collections.Counter(list2)
>>> sum(v3*c2[v1] for v1, v3 in zip(list1, list3))
```

A counter maps each element of the `list2` to its number of occurences: there are `c2[v1]` values `v1` in `list2`.

The time complexity is the same.